# Bind data to component with Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm new to `vue.js` and I'm trying to use `vuex`. Here is my issue:

I have a list of articles (which is a component) linked with a store with `v-for="article in articles` and a computed property:

```
computed: {
        articles() {
            return this.$store.state.articles
        }
    }
```

So here is the data in my store:

```
 state: {
    articles: [{
        title: "Article 1",
        id: 1,
        description: "Article 1",
      }, {
        title: "Article 2",
        id: 2,
        description: "Article 2",
      }
     }]
}
```

When I click on an article, I want it to redirect to the article page template (which is a component) with `<router-link :to="{path: '/article/'+article.id}"></router-link>`.

What I'm trying to do is bind the data of the correct article in the `articlePage` template.

The issue is that if I apply the same computed property to my `articlePage.vue` component with a `v-for`, I will display all of the article on the same page. I would like to display only the matching id component.

How can I do that?

Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 2):

From your comments I understand that you use **vue-router** module
So in your `routes.js` (or structure ) your must have something like this

```
const router = new VueRouter({
   routes: [
    { path: '/articles', component: articlesPage },
    { path: '/article/:id', component: articlePage }
  ]
})
```

Then in your articlePage component you can extract ":id" like this:

```
this.$route.params.id
```

because vue-router gives you access to the object `$route` with methods and properties
Check more here https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html

then you can use it to search the articles array and find the data and present them
e.x.

```
computed:{
   selectedArticle(){
     var article_id = this.$route.params.id;
     var articles = this.$store.state.articles;
     var article = null;
     for(var a=0;a<articles.length;a++){
         if(articles[a].id == article_id ){
           article = articles[a];
           break;
         }
     } 
     return article;
   }
}
```

Comment: Your code makes perfectly sense but for some reason it doesn't work I don't know why :/ Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: Do you receive any errors in console? Please also check the case  that this.$route.params.id is string so convert it with parseInt(this.$route.params.id) as your article id attribute is integer (put before the `return article` , console.log(article) to check if the article was found. Do not forget also at your template to use {{selectedArticle.title}} and not {{article.title}} .

Comment: I don't receive any error, and when I console log it returns null... But it loops correctly because when I console.log(a) it loops through the articles

Comment: if you `console.log` article_id from the expression `this.$route.params.id` in the computed function `selectedArticle` does it print it?

Comment: It does 3 times for some reason (which is the amount of article in the store)